# apportable facebook login error when facebook app is installed

Tags: android, ios, facebook, apportable

I am using **Apportable** to port cocos2d game to android every thing is fine but facebook is headeach...

I have a issue that when I login from my app there are two cases:

1)if facebook is not installed in android device , login dialog open and login properly.

2)but if facebook app installed in android device its redirect to facebook app , i enter my username and password and login my app pop up for permission "(my app name) would like to access your public prifile and friend list." and if I click OK its not login.And if facebook app logged in it will popup permission dialog and nothing happen. what I have to do?

thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering because its may help others.

The solution is **check your apportable Facebook SDK version** and compare it with iOS latest version, it may happen you call a method and its not availabel in the latest version of iOS facebook SDK.

It's happend in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample code for Facebook Login And Wall Post Check this out this demo

Facebook Login & Wall Post  [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fw5xpox5re88q0f/AndroidFacebook.zip)

If any doubt lets comment...

Thanks